# WM_DPICHANGED called in loop with size not returned from WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE

Tags: winapi, highdpi

I'm trying to make our WinAPI application DPI-aware, and ran into an apparently infinite loop where the window constantly receives WM_DPICHANGED. The program always calls SetWindowPos with the lParam of the WM_DPICHANGED message, as the documentation says.

My monitor setup has monitor 1 on the right, 1920x1080, 100% scaling, and monitor 2 on the left, aligned at the bottom, 3840x2160, 150% scaling. Running the following program, move the window so that it straddles the two monitors, but is scaled at 100%. Now, grab the window on the left-hand monitor, and move the window up and down vertically so that it switches between the two resolutions. At some point, it goes into a loop which seems to stall the whole window manager (ctrl-alt-del will interrupt it -- no need to actually terminate the program).

In this loop, the rectangle passed in lParam has size 500x500 for both 96 and 144 DPI! **Why is WM_DPICHANGED getting a rectangle whose size isn't that returned from WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE?**

I know I'm doing something unusual by having the window smaller on the higher DPI monitor (in the real app, our windows have complex layouts which change depending on the resolution).

**Why is this looping and how can we avoid the DPI-change cycle?**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE:
    {
        LPSIZE lpSize = (LPSIZE)lParam;
        int dpi = wParam;
        lpSize->cy = lpSize->cx = (dpi == 96 ? 200 : 500);
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_DPICHANGED:
    {
        LPRECT lpRect = (LPRECT)lParam;
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, nullptr, lpRect->left, lpRect->top, lpRect->right - lpRect->left, lpRect->bottom - lpRect->top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        return 0;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

WCHAR szTitle[] = L"Test";                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[] = L"TESTCLASS";            // the main window class name

ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

   SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE,
      200, 200, 200, 200, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = nullptr;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = nullptr;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. Windows has a lot of per-monitor DPI related bugs, I suspect you've just stumbled across one of them.

Comment: Your window could constantly change monitor which has the largest area of it. To verify use `MonitorFromWindow` - log result to console or file.

Comment: Be aware also that `WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE` is not generated if you use Win+Shift+Arrows to change which screen the window is on. You need to fixup the window size in both `WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE` _and_ `WM_DPICHANGED` to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible to work around this situation by detecting whether the DPI in `wParam` matches that returned by `GetDpiForWindow`, and ignoring `WM_DPICHANGED` in that case.